Why is CSSnano running in my project, even though not installed?
In my project I don't have cssnano installed anymore, but every time I run the webpack build, it still distributes the files (and I mean all files) like they're being minified by cssnano. This happens for the css, the HTML, and javascript too.
cssnano doesn't exist in any of the projects dependencies, and also in the postcss.config.js it is commented out like so:
if (process.env.NODE.ENV === 'production') {
    module.exports = {
        plugins: {
            autoprefixer: {},
            //cssnano: {}
        }
    }
} else {
    module.exports = {
        plugins: {
            autoprefixer: {}
        }
    }
}

Here's what the files in the dist folder look like when they are built:
HTML:
<!doctype html><html><head><title>Index page</title><script defer="defer" src="index.bundle.js"></script><script defer="defer" src="sum.bundle.js"></script><script defer="defer" src="shared.bundle.js"></script><link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body id="index"><a href="about.html"><button type="button">Go To Other Page</button></a><div><h1 class="text"></h1></div></body></html>

CSS:
.example{display:grid;transition:all .5s;-webkit-user-select:none;user-select:none;background:linear-gradient(to bottom, white, black)}#index{background:red}#about{background:#ff0}a{text-decoration:none}div{position:relative;margin:0;width:400px;height:200px;background:#ff0}.text{color:#000}


Javascript bundles:
"use strict";(self.webpackChunkwebpacktutorial=self.webpackChunkwebpacktutorial||[]).push([[57],{115:(e,l,s)=>{var o=s(543),a=s.n(o);const t=e=>{console.log(`Hello ${e}`)};t("in console"),console.log(a().join(["Index","module","loaded!"]," ")),document.getElementsByClassName(".text").appendChild(t("saying words"))}},e=>{e(e.s=115)}]);

I'm not understanding why it's doing this really. I thought uninstalling and removing it from the config file would stop that behaviour from happening.
Thanks for any help!
I've tried uninstalling it, and commenting out the config, but still no dice.
